# I want to change status from a tourist B2 visa to a Work Visa

Tags: usa

Can i change my visa status from a tourist visa to a Work Visa while here in the states? I'm from New Zealand. I can't find any clear answers.

Answer (score 1):

The primary source of information is the [Employment Visas](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/employment.html) page at the US Department of State site.

The visas classified as [Temporary Worker Visas](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/employment/temporary.html) (H, L, O, P, Q) have either very specific requirements, or a waiting list and heaps of paperwork.

The [Exchange Visitor Visa](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/study-exchange/exchange.html) has a link to the [New Zealand and Australia 12-Month Work and Travel Program](https://nz.usembassy.gov/visas/study-exchange/new-zealand-and-australia-twelve-month-work-and-travel-program-2/) which might be a viable option for you. However, there is a limited list of sponsors and you can't just take up employment anywhere.

On that page is also "Can I adjust to a different visa status once I am in the United States?" which unhelpfully states:

> Once you are in the United States you are responsible for maintaining the correct immigration status with U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services (USCIS). For further information on changing to a different visa status once in the United States, you may visit the USCIS website at [uscis.gov](http://www.uscis.gov/).

I finally found the [Change My Nonimmigrant Status](http://www.uscis.gov/visit-united-states/change-my-nonimmigrant-status-category/change-my-nonimmigrant-status) page which states:

> In general, you may apply to change your nonimmigrant status if you were lawfully admitted to the United States with a nonimmigrant visa, your nonimmigrant status remains valid, you have not violated the conditions of your status, and you have not committed any crimes that would make you ineligible.

So, if you find a temporary worker visa category that is applicable for you, then yes, you are allowed to apply for a change of status from B-2 to that work visa.